# Object Object Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a page with modal and a form that I changed the jQuery because the input file.

It's working perfectly, but when I change to Validate.js the success message don't show some values from the form.

This message appears: [Object Object]

I tried to find some answers but nothing help me.

The problem: Last line Success Message.

I tried:

```
+name+
+$name+
+$('#name').text()+
```

I really appreciate some help!

Thanks

Here is the code JS:

```
(function() {
    $('#contactForm').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            //return $('#mailForm').validate().form();

            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var cpf = $("input#cpf").val();
            var rg = $("input#rg").val();
            var expeditor = $("input#expeditor").val();
            var data = $("input#data").val();
            var crm = $("input#crm").val();
            var especialidade = $("input#especialidade").val();
            var nascimento = $("input#nascimento").val();
            var estado_civil = $("input#estado_civil").val();
            var logradouro = $("input#logradouro").val();
            var numero = $("input#numero").val();
            var complemento = $("input#complemento").val();
            var bairro = $("input#bairro").val();
            var municipio = $("input#municipio").val();
            var cep = $("input#cep").val();
            var tel = $("input#tel").val();
            var cel = $("input#cel").val();
            var cel2 = $("input#cel2").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var logradouro2 = $("input#logradouro2").val();
            var numero2 = $("input#numero2").val();
            var complemento2 = $("input#complemento2").val();
            var bairro2 = $("input#bairro2").val();
            var municipio2 = $("input#municipio2").val();
            var cep2 = $("input#cep2").val();
            var tel2 = $("input#tel2").val();
            var email2 = $("input#email2").val();
            var autoridade = $("input#autoridade").val();
            var residente = $("select#residente").val();
            var residente_sim_resposta = $("input#residente_sim_resposta").val();
            var residencia = $("select#residencia").val();
            var residencia_sim_resposta = $("input#residencia_sim_resposta").val();
            var associacao = $("select#associacao").val();
            var associacao_sim_resposta = $("input#associacao_sim_resposta").val();
            var entidade = $("select#entidade").val();
            var entidade_sim_resposta = $("input#entidade_sim_resposta").val();
            var procedimento = $("select#procedimento").val();
            var procedimento_sim_resposta = $("input#procedimento_sim_resposta").val();
            var restritiva = $("select#restritiva").val();
            var restritiva_sim_resposta = $("input#restritiva_sim_resposta").val();
            var administrativa = $("select#administrativa").val();
            var administrativa_sim_resposta = $("input#administrativa_sim_resposta").val();
            var dependencia = $("select#dependencia").val();
            var recusada = $("select#recusada").val();
            var reclamacao = $("select#reclamacao").val();
            var saude = $("select#saude").val();
            var vida = $("select#vida").val();
            var previdencia = $("select#previdencia").val();
            var pagamento = $("select#pagamento").val();
            var correspondencia = $("select#correspondencia").val();

            $("#contactForm").validate({
                 rules: {
                    name: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    cpf: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 14
                    },
                    rg: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 3
                    },
                    expeditor: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 3
                    },
                    data: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 10
                    },
                    crm: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    especialidade: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    nascimento: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 10
                    },
                    estado_civil: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    logradouro: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    numero: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    complemento: {
                       required: false,
                    },
                    bairro: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    municipio: { 
                       required: true,
                    },
                    cep: { 
                      required: true,
                      minlength: 9
                    },
                    tel: { 
                       required: true,
                       minlength: 14
                    },
                    cel: { 
                       required: true,
                       minlength: 15
                    },
                    cel2: { 
                       required: false,
                    },
                    email: { 
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 3
                    },
                    logradouro2: { 
                       required: true,
                    },
                    numero2: { 
                       required: true,
                    },
                    complemento2: { 
                       required: false,
                    },
                    bairro2: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    municipio2: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    cep2: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 9
                    },
                    tel2: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 14
                    },
                    email2: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 3
                    },
                    autoridade: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    residente: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    residente_sim_resposta: {
                       required: false,
                    },
                    residencia: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    residencia_sim_resposta: {
                       required: false,
                    },
                    associacao: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    associacao_sim_resposta: {
                       required: false,
                    },
                    entidade: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    entidade_sim_resposta: {
                       required: false,
                    },
                    procedimento: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    procedimento_sim_resposta: {
                       required: false,
                    },
                    restritiva: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    restritiva_sim_resposta: {
                       required: false,
                    },
                    administrativa: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    administrativa_sim_resposta: {
                       required: false,
                    },
                    dependencia: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    recusada: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    reclamacao: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    saude: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    vida: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    previdencia: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    pagamento: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    correspondencia: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    termos: {
                       required: true,
                    }
                 },
                 messages: {
                    name: {
                       required:"Digite seu nome"                    
                    },
                    cpf: {
                       required: "Digite seu CPF.",
                       minlength : "Digite seu CPF corretamente."
                    },
                    rg: {
                       required: "Digite seu RG.",
                       minlength : "Digite seu RG corretamente."
                    },
                    expeditor: {
                       required: "Digite o Orgão Expeditor.",
                       minlength : "Digite o Orgão Expeditor corretamente."
                    },
                    data: {
                       required: "Digite a data de expedição.",
                       minlength : "Digite a data de expedição corretamente."
                    },
                    crm: {
                       required: "Digite seu CRM."
                    },
                    especialidade: {
                       required: "Digite sua especialidade."
                    },
                    nascimento: {
                       required: "Digite a data de nascimento.",
                       minlength : "Digite a data de nascimento corretamente."
                    },
                    estado_civil: {
                       required: "Digite seu estado civil."
                    },
                    logradouro: {
                       required: "Digite seu endereço."
                    },
                    numero: {
                       required: "Digite o número."
                    },
                    complemento: {
                    },
                    bairro: {
                       required: "Digite o bairro."
                    },
                    municipio:{ 
                       required: "Digite seu município"
                    },
                    cep: { 
                      required : "Digite seu CEP.",
                      minlength: "Digite seu CEP corretamente."
                    },
                    tel: { 
                       required: "Digite seu telefone.",
                       minlength: "Digite seu telefone corretamente."
                    },
                    cel: { 
                       required: "Digite seu celular.",
                       minlength: "Digite seu celular corretamente."
                    },
                    cel2: { 
                    },
                    email: { 
                       required: "Digite seu email",
                       email: 'Por favor digite um email válido'
                    },
                    logradouro2: { 
                       required: "Digite seu endereço."
                    },
                    numero2: { 
                       required: "Digite o número."
                    },
                    complemento2: { 
                    },
                    bairro2: {
                       required: "Digite o bairro."
                    },
                    municipio2: {
                       required: "Digite seu município"
                    },
                    cep2: {
                       required : "Digite seu CEP.",
                       minlength: "Digite seu CEP corretamente."
                    },
                    tel2: {
                       required: "Digite seu telefone.",
                       minlength: "Digite seu telefone corretamente."
                    },
                    email2: {
                       required: "Digite seu email",
                       email: 'Por favor digite um email válido'
                    },
                    autoridade: {
                       required: "Digite a autoridade que outorgou o Registro Profissional (Conselho/UF, etc)."
                    },
                    residente: {
                       required: "Resposta obrigatória."
                    },
                    residente_sim_resposta: {
                    },
                    residencia: {
                       required: "Resposta obrigatória."
                    },
                    residencia_sim_resposta: {
                    },
                    associacao: {
                       required: "Resposta obrigatória."
                    },
                    associacao_sim_resposta: {
                    },
                    entidade: {
                       required: "Resposta obrigatória."
                    },
                    entidade_sim_resposta: {
                    },
                    procedimento: {
                       required: "Resposta obrigatória."
                    },
                    procedimento_sim_resposta: {
                    },
                    restritiva: {
                       required: "Resposta obrigatória."
                    },
                    restritiva_sim_resposta: {
                    },
                    administrativa: {
                       required: "Resposta obrigatória."
                    },
                    administrativa_sim_resposta: {
                    },
                    dependencia: {
                       required: "Resposta obrigatória."
                    },
                    recusada: {
                       required: "Resposta obrigatória."
                    },
                    reclamacao: {
                       required: "Resposta obrigatória."
                    },
                    saude: {
                       required: "Resposta obrigatória."
                    },
                    vida: {
                       required: "Resposta obrigatória."
                    },
                    previdencia: {
                       required: "Resposta obrigatória."
                    },
                    pagamento: {
                       required: "Selecione a forma de pagamento."
                    },
                    correspondencia: {
                       required: "Selecione o recebimento de correspondência."
                    },
                    termos: {
                       required: "Você deve aceitar os termos antes de continuar."
                    }
                 },
                 debug: true,
                 errorElement: "em",
                 errorContainer: $("#warning, #summary"),
                 errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo( element.parent() );
                 } 
             });
             var flag= $('#contactForm').valid();
             if(!flag){
                 return false;
             }
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#contactForm button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
          },
        success: function(data) {

          console.log(data);
          $("#contactForm").addClass('submited');
          $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
          $("#contactForm button[type='submit']").attr('disabled', false);
          $("#contactForm .message").delay(3000).hide(500);

          // Success message

          $('#success3').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
          $('#success3 > .alert-success').html("<div class='header'><h3>Trabalhe Protegido</h3><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button></div>");
          $('#success3 > .alert-success').append("<div class='text-center ptb-20 prl-20'><i class='icon-trabalhe-protegido'></i><h5 class='mt-15'>Contratação realizada com sucesso!</h5><h5>Em breve você receberá um email com todas as informações.</h5></div>");
          $('#success3 > .alert-success').append("<div class='prl-20 hidden-xs'><h6>Dados do Proponente:</h6><p>Nome: "+$('#name').text()+"</p><p>CPF: "+$('#cpf').text()+"</p><p>Email: "+$('#email').text()+"</p><p>Telefone: "+$('#tel').text()+"</p></div>");

          //clear all fields
          //$('#success2').delay(4000).hide(500);
          $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
          $("#status").html(xhr.responseText);      
        }
    }); 
})();
```

Comment: console log your object and see which property you want to access

Answer (score 0):

Try `.val()` instead of `.text()`.  Since an `input` is not a container element, there is nothing to obtain via `.text()`.

[Read the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

> *"The `.text()` method **cannot** be used on form **inputs** or scripts. To set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the `.val()` method."*